# Laravel dynamic pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my app I use custom class for replicate tables during the tests. This class create new tables with `_test` postfix and tell eloquent to work with them. But when I work with "many to many" relations I need to specify pivot table name too. Is it possible to change pivot table during runtime application?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, then you want to be able to change your tables in many-to-many relationship dynamically.

please pay attention to source code of belongsToMany relationship:

```
public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
{
    // If no relationship name was passed, we will pull backtraces to get the
    // name of the calling function. We will use that function name as the
    // title of this relation since that is a great convention to apply.
    if (is_null($relation)) {
        $relation = $this->guessBelongsToManyRelation();
    }

    // First, we'll need to determine the foreign key and "other key" for the
    // relationship. Once we have determined the keys we'll make the query
    // instances as well as the relationship instances we need for this.
    $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

    $relatedKey = $relatedKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

    // If no table name was provided, we can guess it by concatenating the two
    // models using underscores in alphabetical order. The two model names
    // are transformed to snake case from their default CamelCase also.
    if (is_null($table)) {
        $table = $this->joiningTable($related);
    }

    return new BelongsToMany(
        $instance->newQuery(), $this, $table, $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $relation
    );
}
```

you can define the table there. So I suggest you to do as following:(consider a Many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Company` model)

```
public function users(){
     $table = env('APP_ENV') == 'production' ? 'table_name' : 'test_table_name';
     $this->belongsToMany(User::class, $table);
}
```

and do the same for Company model
I never tested this but basically it should work.

Comment: This is a bad solution. It means that i need to modify each belongsToMany relation in my app. I need something like that: $model->users()->setTable('table_name_test')